# Populate column with query results in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Table columns structured like:

**longitude, latitude, gid, Hash**

*-78.885636, 36.854, 1, empty*

Using PostgreSQL 9.4 and trying to update column *Hash* with results of a geohash function:

```
SELECT ST_GeoHash(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude::float, latitude::float), 4326))
FROM my_table;
```

To update the column, I am using:

```
UPDATE my_table SET Hash = (SELECT ST_GeoHash(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude::float, latitude::float), 4326))
FROM my_table);
```

But I get an error:

```
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.
```

I'm new to this so I may be asking a tedious question.  Any help would be appreciated.  For now I'll be RTFM-ing.

Comment: is there any primary key in my_table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
UPDATE my_table SET "Hash" = (
SELECT ST_GeoHash(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude::float, latitude::float), 4326))
 FROM my_table p
 WHERE my_table.gid = p.gid
);
```

Answer (score 3):

To update `Hash` column with a calculated value you need to use this query, where `gid` is a primary key(probably you need to change it).

```
UPDATE my_table 
  SET Hash = my_table_2.geo_hash
  FROM 
    (SELECT gid, 
            ST_GeoHash(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude::float, latitude::float), 4326)) as geo_hash
      FROM my_table) as my_table_2
 WHERE my_table.gid = my_table_2.gid
```